# Image onload for static images

Tags: javascript, events

I know that for the image onload to work you have to set the src after the onload handler was attached. However I want to attach onload handlers to images that are static in my HTML. Right now I do that in the following way (using jQquery):

```
<img id='img1' src='picture.jpg'>
```

```
$('#img1').load( function() {
 alert('foo');
})
.attr('src', $('img1').attr('src'));
```

But this is rather ugly and has the obvious flow that it can only be done for selectors that match only one image. Is there any other, nicer way to do this?

**edit**
What I meant by that it can only be done for selector that match only one image is that when doing this:

```
<img class='img1' src='picture.jpg'>
<img class='img1' src='picture2.jpg'>
```

```
$('.img1').load( function() {
 alert('foo');
})
.attr('src', $('.img1').attr('src'));
```

That both images will have src='picture.jpg'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can trigger the event (or it's handler) directly by calling `.trigger()` or `.load()`.

If you know that you want the event, because you know that the images are already loaded, then you can do it like this:

```
$('#img1').load(function() {
    alert('foo');
  })
  .trigger('load');  // fires the load event on the image
```

If you are running your script on document ready or some moment where it isn't yet clear if the images are there or not, then I would use something like this:

```
$('img.static')
  .load(function(){
    alert('foo');
    return false; // cancel event bubble
  })
  .each(function(){
    // trigger events for images that have loaded,
    // other images will trigger the event once they load
    if ( this.complete && this.naturalWidth !== 0 ) {
      $( this ).trigger('load');
    }
  });
```

Be warned that the load event bubbles (jQuery 1.3) and you might possibly be triggering a load handler on the document prematurely if you don't cancel the bubble in the img handler.

For the record: The `img.src=img.src` triggering solution will unfortunately not work correctly on Safari. You will need to set the `src` to something else (like # or about:blank) and then back for reload to happen.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I turned Borgars answer into a plugin, here it is:

```
$.fn.imageLoad = function(fn){
    this.load(fn);
    this.each( function() {
        if ( this.complete && this.naturalWidth !== 0 ) {
            $(this).trigger('load');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You should return ```this``` at the end in order to allow for chaining :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is really a question about jQuery selectors.  If you would like to match all your image elements then you can use `img` instead of `#img1` as your selector.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to images where you want this functionality and use that class in the jQuery selector.

```
$('.static-image').load( function(){ ... } );
```