# Exception when using canvas (0x80040111 NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm having some trouble writing a JavaScript paint tool. It's a unit test and in the future will be used as a component for a larger project I'm working on. It runs in a canvas but when I try to run it, I get this error message:

```
Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE) [nsIDOMCanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage]"  nsresult: "0x80040111 (NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE)"  location: "JS frame :: http://rasmvillage/canvasapp/js/lib.js :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 52"  data: no]
```

I'm using the jquery library

The HTML is nothing special. Just a div#container with a canvas#imageID and canvas#boardID inside of it. Can someone help me figure out what's wrong? Thanks.

Comment: A 4 year-old story about this error: http://ejohn.org/blog/why-20011-happened-so-fast/

Comment: ... and the same error on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850312/canvas-drawimage-doesnt-draw-images-the-first-time

Answer (score 2):

As indicated on [canvas drawImage doesn't draw images the first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850312/canvas-drawimage-doesnt-draw-images-the-first-time), make sure you don't operate on images until the images `onload` has fired.  More advice on [Image onload for static images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632765/image-onload-for-static-images), including a jQuery plugin that may help.